# Django IndexError at / list index out of range

Tags: python, django

I was having problems migrating and when it finally worked this appeared on the home page. Some of the other pages work, and it seems to just be the home page.

Error Messages:

```
Internal Server Error: /
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Users\pc\formula_zone\lib\site- 
 packages\django\core\handlers\exception.py", line 34, in inner
response = get_response(request)
File "C:\Users\pc\formula_zone\lib\site- 
packages\django\core\handlers\base.py", line 126, in _get_response
response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)
File "C:\Users\pc\formula_zone\lib\site- 
packages\django\core\handlers\base.py", line 124, in _get_response
response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
File "C:\Users\pc\Downloads\formula_zone\mysite\racing\views.py", line 15, 
in racing_stats
ra = races[0]
File "C:\Users\pc\formula_zone\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\query.py", 
 line 303, in __getitem__
return qs._result_cache[0]
IndexError: list index out of range
```

I think its on the views.py so here's that code as well.

```
def racing_stats(request, race_id=None):
drivers = Driver.objects.all().order_by('lap_time')
races = Race.objects.all()
for racer in drivers:
    driver_controller.update_race_time(racer)

if race_id:
    ra = Race.objects.get(rac_id=race_id)
else:
    ra = races[0]

buttons = []
for r in races:
    buttons.append((r.rac_id, r.race_name))
context = {
    'drivers': drivers,
    'active_race': ra,
    'buttons': buttons
}
return render(request, 'racing/racing_stats.html', context)


def race_list(request):
races = Race.objects.all()

context = {
    'races': races,
}

return render(request, 'racing/races.html', context)


def race_detail(request, pk):
    race_ds = get_object_or_404(Race, pk=pk)
    print(race_ds)
    return render(request, 'racing/race_detail.html', 
    {'race_detail': race_ds})
```

Comment: `ra = races[0]` is the problematic line. Looks like `Race.objects.all()` returns an empty queryset.

Comment: Thank you! I had to delete my database, so that may explain that problem. Going to add some items in there and then check